# Communication between Activity and Fragment for sending values

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

Hi guys then in the program you see below I should perform this series of steps:

**1) Fragment1 (Rapportini) I go to Activity2 (Articoli)**

**2) select an element and return to Fragment1 (Rapportini) passing the value as intent**

**3) the OnActivityResult method reads the intent and adds it to an arraylist**

My problem is that the OnActivityResult method is not called! Why this happens, how can I solve it?

**Activity 2 (Articoli) - Code:**

```
  Articolo a = (Articolo) ArticoliRicerca.get(position);
                Intent tabRapportini = new Intent(ArticoliActivity.this, RapportiniActivity.class);
                tabRapportini.putExtra("articoloselezionato", a);
                setResult(ArticoliActivity.RESULT_OK,tabRapportini);
                System.out.println("\n  Hai fatto tap  \n");
                finish();
```

**Fragment result  (Rapportini Fragment ):**

```
public class RapportiniActivity extends Fragment {


    private View view;
    private ArrayList ArticoloSelezionati = new ArrayList();

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_rapportini, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final Button btnGeneraRapportino = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttongenera_rapportino);
        final Button btnAggiungiArticoli = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_inserimento_articoli);
        final EditText txtNote = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.EditText_Note);


        btnAggiungiArticoli.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent articoliintent = new Intent(RapportiniActivity.this.getActivity(), ArticoliActivity.class);
                startActivity(articoliintent);

            }
        });

        //Configuro la funzione Listener sul login button
        btnGeneraRapportino.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Prima di procedere con la generazione del rapportino è necessario controllare che le note siano inserite
                if (txtNote.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                    Rapportino r = new Rapportino();
                    String ImageBase64 = r.GeneraRapportinoPrivato(txtNote.getText().toString());
                    try {
                        //byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(ImageBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        //System.out.println("\n Decode String: "+decodedString);
                        //Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                        //img.setImageBitmap(bp);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.print("Errore: " + ex);
                    }
                } else {
                    Support.Notification(RapportiniActivity.this.getActivity(), "Attenzione", "Non hai inserito le note");
                }
            }
        });


    }


    /*  Tipologie di result code:
         1) Articolo

    */

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == 1) {
            System.out.println("\n Hai selezionato un articolo");
            Articolo a = (Articolo) data.getSerializableExtra("articoloselezionato");
            ArticoloSelezionati.add(a);

        }
        System.out.println("\n Articolo selezionati: " + ArticoloSelezionati.size());
    }


}
```

Comment: I believe your explanation is misleading, you are calling `Rapportini` an `Activity` when it's actually a `Fragment`. `Activity` is a container where `Fragment` is stored, they can't communicate through an intent.

Comment: @LieForBananas I corrected above! How can I make them communicate?

Comment: There is a [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating) page about it, and you can find a lot of resources online if you search "Activity Fragment communication". And I suggest that you read about [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) , they cannot be initialised by an intent, it's done using Fragment Transactions, and in your Activity's UI (in XML) you have to have a "place" for a fragment.

Comment: @LieForBananas For what is it possible to passelement arraylist from the fragment to the activity for reference? Maybe using C ++! or better than I smoke less and use the tutorials on the android site!

Comment: Why C++?? Read the documentation, before passing any values you need to initialise the Fragment properly, not with an Intent.

Comment: @LieForBananas I solved using a singleton and inserting the elements inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code:

```
Intent articoliintent = new Intent(RapportiniActivity.this.getActivity(), ArticoliActivity.class);
startActivity(articoliintent);
```

use startActivityForResult

Comment: @riki Use proper naming conventions, don't mislead Fragment to Activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple. Just make sure that the activity containing `RapportiniActivity` (which is a fragment), has `onActivityResult` overridden in it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

And your code should work.

Comment: with your method I have this error:  in RapportiniActivity cannot override onActivityResult(int,int,Intent) in Fragment
attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public

Comment: I told to put it this method in activity containing `RapportiniActivity`, the host activity. Let the `onActivityResult` in `RapportiniActivity` be the same as you have given in question

Comment: I can not understand what you mean! I put the method you told me in RapportiniActivity and I have that mistake! What would you say?

Comment: What starts RapportiniActivity?